# Origin of term “Pudlink”

Tags: etymology

My grandfather used to use the term “pudlink” (POOD-link) as an endearing term for a baby. He was Slovak, and also spoke Czech (my grandmother is Czech, but doesn’t know the origin of the term). Where does this term come from?

Comment: Was he from Podolínec?

Comment: Are you sure you remember the word well? I am a native Czech speaker and mostly understand Slovak (those languages are highly mutually intelligible, they sound much like a dialect of a single language). I have heard the word “pudlink” (maybe rather written as “pudling”), but in a very different meaning: pudl (poodle) + puding = some food made from a dog. Also Google suggests the same.

Comment: BTW, when Googling just for “pudlink” and restricting just to Slovak webpages, I can see just four results: https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_sk&client=firefox-b-1-m&tbs=lr%3Alang_1cs&q=pudlink&oq=pudlink&aqs=heirloom-srp..0l2 Two of them are just a username on an adult site  (amateri), two of them are related to eating dogs. (Note that “pudlink” or “pudling” in the meaning of eating dogs is quite informal and humorous.)

Comment: @v6ak, it could definitely be slightly off, and I have no idea how to spell the word my family is saying :) Could it be something like a "little dog"?

Comment: @JesseBeder The closest word that comes in my mind is Czech pudlík [ˈpudl̩i:k], which is a diminutive of pudl [ˈpudl̩] (=poodle). I am a bit unsure about Slovak suffixes, but I am afraid that they are not going to do so close match. However, your Czech grandmother would probably know that.